# Why isn't there any output on my console?

Tags: click, raphael

This is my code that is not writing output to my console:

```
for( var i= 1; i < lineData.length; i++){
            var dot = paper.circle(i*5, i*5, 5);
            dot.click(function(){
                console.log("test");
            });
}
```

In other parts of my code, click interactions are working fine.
Is it because i use the same variable all the time?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked fine.

Are you sure that you click correctly on the border of the circle?
Without further attributes, you have to click on the border of your circle to trigger event.

better try paper.circle(x,y,r).attr({'fill':'white'}); to click the whole circle.

Comment: I found the real reason here. There was an invisible 100% width/height rectangle to catch whitespace clicks, but it blocked my events from triggering. that happens, when you work co-op i think..
also i didnt know, that you cant click it, when its not filled. makes sense, but still .. thanks for the hint